# Disable zoom when reached max or min zoom level

Tags: leaflet, zoom

Is it possible to set the map to a min/maxZoom level so that it's not possible to zoom further and the current map-view doesn't change?

Comment: There's options named, literally, `minZoom` and `maxZoom` in the map.

Comment: yes, but these options don't prevent zooming further, it just hides the layer/map. What I'm looking for is a way to "freeze" the map when it reaches the min-/maxZoom level so that the map is still visible.

Comment: They do prevent zooming further. See e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/uHjJcBEIJEVhFJQY

Comment: oh, wow, thanks! I did use minZoom/maxZoom inside layers but not on the initial map. Can you provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and it may be useful for other people.